# how to replace contemporary values in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to write in a single "file.cfg" the values of two variables generated by two independent scripts. The two variables are constantly updated and saved in the "file.cfg".
Below is an example of my work.

example "file.cfg" content:

```
a=null
b=null
```

example "script_a.sh" update "a" value with:

```
#!/bin/bash
while : do
    .............
    val_a=1 
    sed -i "s/^\(a=\).*/\1$val_a/" file.cfg
    .............
done
```

example "script_b.sh" update "b" value with:

```
#!/bin/bash
while : do
    .............
    val_b=2 
    sed -i "s/^\(b=\).*/\1$val_b/" file.cfg
    .............
done
```

The scripts work perfectly and the values are updated. But if the two scripts are executed simultaneously one of the two values is not updated.

I discovered that sed with the "-i" option creates a temporary file that is overwritten by the two simultaneous operations.
How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1408534/432690) exploits the idea of lockfile. There is another utility: `flock(1)`. From [its manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html):

> `flock [options] file|directory command [arguments]`
>   `flock [options] file|directory -c command`
>   […]
>
> This utility manages `flock(2)` locks from within shell scripts or from the command line.
>
> The first and second of the above forms wrap the lock around the execution of a command, in a manner similar to `su(1)` or `newgrp(1)`. They lock a specified file or directory, which is created (assuming appropriate permissions) if it does not already exist. By default, if the lock cannot be immediately acquired, `flock` waits until the lock is available.

And because it uses [`flock(2)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html), I believe the kernel guarantees no two processes can hold a lock for the same file:

> `LOCK_EX` Place an exclusive lock. Only one process may hold an exclusive lock for a given file at a given time.

In your scripts, instead of `sed …` run `flock some_lockfile sed …`, e.g.

```
flock some_lockfile sed -i "s/^\(a=\).*/\1$val_a/" file.cfg
```

And that's it, the lock gets released when `sed` exits. The only disadvantages are:

- `some_lockfile` may already be in use as a lockfile; the safe way is to use `mktemp` to create a temporary file and use *it*;
- at the end you need to remove `some_lockfile` (I guess you don't want to leave it as garbage); but if anything else uses the file (probably not as a lockfile), you may not want to remove it; again, `mktemp` is the way to go: create a temporary file, use it, remove it – regardless of what other processes do.

Why not `flock file.cfg sed …` then? It would lock the exact file that is operated on; this wouldn't leave garbage at all. Why not?

Well, because this is flawed. To understand it let's see what [(GNU) `sed -i`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options) exactly does:

> `-i[SUFFIX]`
>   `--in-place[=SUFFIX]`
>
> This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. GNU `sed` does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output.
>
> […]
>
> When the end of the file is reached, the temporary file is renamed to the output file’s original name. The extension, if supplied, is used to modify the name of the old file before renaming the temporary file, thereby making a backup copy.

I have tested that `flock` locks inode rather than name (path). This means just after `sed -i` renames the temporary file to the original name (`file.cfg` in your case), the lock no longer applies to the original name.

Now consider the following scenario:

1. The first `flock file.cfg sed -i … file.cfg` locks the original file and works with it.
2. Before the first `sed` finishes, another `flock file.cfg sed -i … file.cfg` arises. This new `flock` targets the original `file.cfg` and waits for the first lock to be released.
3. The first `sed` moves its temporary file to the original name and exits. The first lock is released.
4. The second `flock` spawns the second `sed` which now opens the new `file.cfg`. This file is not the original file (because of different inode). But the second `flock` targeted and locked the original file, not the one the second `sed` just opened!
5. Before the second `sed` finishes, another `flock file.cfg sed -i … file.cfg` arises. This new `flock` checks the current `file.cfg` and finds it's *not locked*; it locks the file and spawns `sed`. The third `sed` begins to read the current `file.cfg`.
6. There are now two `sed -i` processes reading from the same file in parallel. Whichever ends first, loses – the other one will overwrite the results eventually by moving its independent copy to the original name.

That's why you need `some_lockfile` with a rock solid inode number.

Answer (score 1):

A lockfile should work well, if the lockfile exists then some process is using the target file & other processes will have to wait.

If you've got the `lockfile-progs` package then you could use it to check for an existing valid lock (within the last 5 minutes) with `lockfile-check`, and similar `lockfile-create` & `lockfile-remove`.

> Note that these lockfiles *do not lock or block access to the file,* but are just informative so your scripts know not to interfere with each other.

`lockfile-create` has a default delay if a lockfile already exists, it will wait until the file's unlocked before proceeding. Here's an except from it's man page:

> `-r retry-count, --retry retry-count`
>
> Try to lock filename retry-count times  before  giving  up.   Each  attempt  will  be
>              delayed  a bit longer than the last (in 5 second increments) until reaching a maximum
>              delay of one minute between retries.  If retry-count is unspecified, the default is 9
>              which will give up after 180 seconds (3 minutes) if all 9 lock attempts fail.

Here's a basic example allowing multiple commands while file.cfg is locked (including an exit if `lockfile-create` fails), but see the man page for more details.:

```
lockfile-create file.cfg  || { echo "lockfile-create failed, exiting now"; exit; }
...
sed -i ... file.cfg
...
lockfile-remove file.cfg
```

If you need the lockfile for longer than 5 minutes, use `lockfile-touch` to "run forever, touching the lock once every minute until killed." Here's an excerpt from the man page:

```
Locking a file during a lengthy process:

     lockfile-create /some/file
     lockfile-touch /some/file &
     # Save the PID of the lockfile-touch process
     BADGER="$!"
     do-something-important-with /some/file
     kill "${BADGER}"
     lockfile-remove /some/file
```

If you did want to do something special while waiting for the file to unlock, you could use a while loop like this, but there could be a window of few milliseconds (0.003s in my `time` tests) between checking and locking the file, but then lockfile-create will just wait until it's safe to proceed anyway

```
while lockfile-check file.cfg
do
  echo doing stuff waiting for lock to clear
  sleep 1
done

lockfile-create file.cfg || exit
...
sed -i ... file.cfg
...
lockfile-remove file.cfg
```

And as long as both scripts use & respect lockfiles, `sed` should never be able to replace the file while it's unlocked, so there should be no file copying & renaming conflicts.

---

Or there's other similar options like:

- `dotlockfile`
- your own `test -a FILE` & `touch`...
- `flock` as in [Kamil's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1408606/307834) is in the `coreutils` package which is nice
- Store the values in a database program that can handle simultaneous access safely

Comment: Actually `lockfile-create` will wait if the files's already locked, I'll edit in it's `-r` option info... so the while loop's not even necessary if you're happy with it's default delay. It's [described as](https://packages.debian.org/sid/lockfile-progs) *"guaranteed compatible with Debian's file locking policies"* so I think should perform equivalent to flock... @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: The path/inode sed problem is interesting, but assuming both processes create a lockfile before starting sed, and clear the lockfile when sed's finished & the filename's "stable" I don't think there can be a conflict, since it creates an actual `file.cfg.lock`, so it's similar to your answer using `some_lockfile` that needs cleaning (`lockfile-remove` here) afterwards.

Comment: Those sound valid, I'll edit in a bit about "holding" the lock for longer, and an "exit on fail" for the code example

Answer (score 0):

[sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied). The default operation mode is to break symbolic and hard links. This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and --copy.
>
> -c, --copy
>
> use copy instead of rename when shuffling files in -i mode. While this will avoid breaking links (symbolic or hard), the resulting editing operation is not atomic. This is rarely the desired mode; --follow-symlinks is usually enough, and it is both faster and more secure.

Have a look whenever you got some aliases setup or what your command looks like exactly. According to the man page it shouldn't be creating a backup if you just use `-i`.

It doesn't mean both couldn't access the file simultaneously and overwrite each others changes. Using a mutex or similar might be advisable in that situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a bit generic though, could you elaborate on it?

Comment: Elaborate on what? Have a look at this rubber chicken explanation about what a [mutex is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558/6590026) if you're unsure about that. How to implement it depends on you. To setup a mutex you could use something like [`flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock).

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic real-time update problem: `script_a.sh` reads `file.cfg`, and before it writes any changes, `script_b.sh` reads the same information; then, whichever script writes its update first, its changes will be overwritten when the other script posts its update. It does not matter whether the updates are done through a temporary file or by writing direct.

There is no native semaphore or mutex handling within `bash`, but you can use the `file.cfg` itself by adding lines to your scripts, eg in `script_a.sh`:-

```
#!/bin/bash
while : do
    .............
    while ! mv file.cfg file.cfg_a 2>/dev/nul; do sleep 0.1; done
    val_a=1
    sed -i "s/^\(a=\).*/\1$val_a/" file.cfg_a
    mv file.cfg_a file.cfg
    .............
done
```

The changes to `script_b.sh` are similar, except that the file is renamed to `file.cfg_b` for updating.

By using a rename command, the script both checks the availability of the file for updating and obtains unique access in a single, uninterruptible process.

I never like polling loops, but without compiling code which supports functions to handle semaphores and mutexes, this is the best that can be easily done.

Note that some versions of `sleep` do not support fractional delays, in which case you will need to delay for the minimum of a second before retrying, unless you use a different utility.

Comment: Best solution for now !!! ;)

Comment: @Jax2171 Warnings and concerns: (1) Obviously this will overwrite the already existing `file.cfg_a`, if any. A safe way is to create a temporary file (`mktemp -p ./`) and to overwrite *it*. (2) "The two variables are constantly updated". This makes sense when there's a final tool that opens `file.cfg` *at random times* (otherwise it would be enough to update the values once, one by one, just before the final tool starts). The final tool now needs to cope with the situation when `file.cfg` is temporarily missing. (3) In general you cannot be sure `mv` is atomic, but atomicity is *crucial* here.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Thanks for your comments. (1) `file.cfg_a` and `file.cfg_b` were intended as files unique to this procedure, but any other reserved names would do, including those generated by `mktemp`. (2) It would be better to have a single process doing the updates, maybe taking `sed` commands from an input pipe, but this is a lot more complex, so I didn't suggest it. My simpler solution requires that `file.cfg` exists before either script is run. (3) A rename will either succeed or fail: it can't be interrupted, allowing `file.cfg` to be renamed to two different files.

Comment: (1) OK. (2) The point is there's probably a program the `file.cfg` is intended for; it needs now be prepared to not find the file and to wait for it to *reappear*. (3) True, I guess, if every `mv` uses `rename(2)`. But if it's copy+delete, the issue is not about `file.cfg` to be renamed to two different files. It's about `mv file.cfg file.cfg_b` copying the *partial* file while `mv file.cfg_a file.cfg` is still running. This may happen if there's a multi-threaded FUSE involved or if the files are under different mountpoints. It's not obvious a slight change to `/tmp/file.cfg_a` may be unsafe.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - (2) OK. I hadn't considered how the file would be processed. I guess the file reader would need a polling loop similar to those in the scripts. (3) As I understand it, `mv` copies and deletes only when the target is on a different file system, which is not the case here.

Comment: (3) Not the case here (although FUSE may be), but the point of SE is to create a knowledge base for users with similar problems yet to come. You said "any other reserved names would do" and this is true. Similarly they may think any other available paths would do. They may enter a different filesystem thinking it's not a big deal. (Hey! This guy is right about `mktemp`. Unfortunately my `mktemp` doesn't support `-p` so I'll just drop it. Isn't `/tmp` for temporary files anyway?) Warning them is the right thing to do.